# RSA-PSSR with a server-side scripting language (php, perl, python, shell, ...)

Tags: php, python, perl, cryptography, openssl

I'm developing a cryptographic software license system based on digital signature with message recovery (RSA-PSSR).
It means that the signed message (in this case, the license block) is encoded directly in the signature (where we usually encode only the hash of the message that we want to sign).

The license keys will be generated on a server, with a private RSA key, and will be verified in the client code, with the public key.

For now, I have developped the server and client code in C++, with the library Crypto++, and everything is working well.
Now, I want to rewrite the server code in a scripting language like PHP, Perl or Python, because my web hosting service don't accept native code.

What scripting language supports the RSA-PSSR scheme ?
I have done a quick search with Google but I haven't found any information about this.

Comment: An alternative solution could be to use openssl commands in a shell script. Is it possible to sign the message itself (and not a digest) with an openssl command?

Comment: Are you aware that PSS-R is patented?

Answer (score 2):

[phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), supports PSS.  Just do $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PSS).  Doesn't do PSS-R though...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any ***scripting*** languages supporting Probabilistic Signature Scheme.

However, ***Perl*** does have PSS support:

- [Crypt::RSA::SS::PSS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt%3a%3aRSA%3a%3aSS%3a%3aPSS). Use sample in "On Perl" [chapter 11.5](http://www.onperl.net/Public-Key-Cryptography)
- [Chilkat RSA Perl Library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/rsa-perl.asp). Chilkat, as far as I know, has libraries for many other languages as well.

I am not sure if either of those support PSS-R (with message recovery).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will look at the Chilkat library, but I'm not sure if I will be able to use it with my web hosting service.